# Apache restarting - Faulting module name: ntdll.dll php_ldap.dll

Tags: php, apache, ldap, windows-server-2016

I have a problem with my apache webserver.

every time I try to start an LDAP request, the webserver restarts

Windows Server2016
16GB RAM

Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/5.6.40

so I checked on another server on the same VM Ware and get the same result

I added to httpd.conf the following code but helped nothing

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize    8888888
</IfModule>
```

Windows event

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.43.0, time stamp: 0x5e9f60a7
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.14393.1715, time stamp: 0x59b0d03e
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f8363
Faulting process id: 0x18b0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6449534f6a6bf
Faulting application path: G:\wld_tool\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 117b17d3-6f27-4544-a1c7-4bb764c8bafb
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

apache error log

```
Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.641960 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH00428: Parent: child process 6320 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] mod_socache_shmcb.c(398): AH00821: shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] mod_socache_shmcb.c(412): AH00822: for 511944 bytes (512000 including header), recommending 32 subcaches, 88 indexes each
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] mod_socache_shmcb.c(449): AH00824: shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] mod_socache_shmcb.c(451): AH00825: subcache_num = 32
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] mod_socache_shmcb.c(453): AH00826: subcache_size = 15992
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] mod_socache_shmcb.c(455): AH00827: subcache_data_offset = 2128
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] mod_socache_shmcb.c(457): AH00828: subcache_data_size = 13864
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] mod_socache_shmcb.c(459): AH00829: index_num = 88
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [socache_shmcb:info] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH00830: Shared memory socache initialised
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.754968 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:58.755969 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.43 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.43, Library: OpenSSL/1.1.1g
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:59.925030 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH00455: Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/5.6.40 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:59.925030 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH00456: Server built: Apr 21 2020 14:07:49
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:59.925030 2020] [mpm_winnt:info] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH80000: Distributed by: The Apache Haus
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:59.925030 2020] [mpm_winnt:info] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH80001: Compiled with: Visual Studio 2017
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:59.925030 2020] [core:notice] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH00094: Command line: '\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d /xampp/apache'
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:59.925030 2020] [core:debug] [pid 4580:tid 700] log.c(1568): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: no (0)
[Wed Jun 17 13:04:59.928027 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4580:tid 700] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 11568
```

Code where the webserver restarts

```
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap,$ldapuser,$pw)
```

```
// connect to active directory
   $ldap = ldap_connect("ldaps://xx.xx.xxx",636);  // must be a valid LDAP server!
   $ldapuser="uid=xxxxxx,ou=people,ou=pg,o=world";
   $pw="xxxxx";

   ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
   ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
   //ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
   $filter="(|(ExtShortName=".$user."))";
   echo $filter;
   $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap,$ldapuser,$pw);

   $result = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn,$filter);
```

please help